# Блокировка экрана Android

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно заблокировать экран устройства? 
Вот так я вывожу телефон  из сна и снимаю блокировку:

//метод для пробуждения и разблокировки экрана

```
@Override 
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD); }
```

Но как сделать обратное, не могу понять. Спасибо всем, кто откликнется.

Comment: @semiromid, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно в манифест добавить permission - android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

Если нужно наоборот сделать, чтобы девайс не засыпал - в атрибутах активити указать **android:keepScreenOn="true"** или метод setKeepScreenOn().